# Slicing Numpy ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, index-error, numpy-slicing

I have used numpy to split a string at each `,`. The output shows the split words. When I want to retrive first element, I get the following error:

`IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 0-dimensional, but 1 were indexed.`

## Code

```
item = "3C2B,FF8BFF5F008C,64,2021-08-01T18:00:01Z,2a* "

item_value = np.char.split(item, sep = ',')

print(item_value)
> ['3C2B', 'FF8BFF5F008C', '64', '2021-08-01T18:00:01Z', '2a*']

print(type(item_value)) 
> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

device_id = item_value[0]
```

Output:

```
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 0-dimensional, but 1 were indexed.
```

Expected output: 3C2B

Comment: What is `item` and what is `item_value.shape`?

Comment: use `alist=item.split(',')`, the strings own split method.

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.str.split` instead of `np.char.split`.

The following code works fine.

```
item = '3C2B,FF8BFF5F008C,64,2021-08-01T18:00:01Z,2a*'
item_value = np.str.split(item, sep = ',')
device_id = item_value[0]
print(device_id)
```

Output:

```
3C2B
```